# Reusing the same MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am displaying a MFMailComposeViewController every time a button is clicked on my app. If i understand correctly, the 'save draft' option of the controller will work only if i use the same MFMailComposeViewController instance.

However, the following method is invoked only the first time i hit the cancel the button:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
```

If i use the same MFMailComposeViewController instance again, this method is not invoked so i am not able to dismiss the controller.
I tried setting the mailComposeDelegate property before every time the controller will be shown but it did not solve the problem. How can i fix it?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get the draft from `MFMailComposeViewController`, if you select `Save Draft`, it saves a Draft in Mail Client, check your mail client for the Draft, so no need of retaining the instance.

Comment: If i use another MFMailComposeViewController instance i don't see the draft.

Comment: @ErikSapir: Actually, when you reusing the same mail composer, it is not showing the draft email, it is showing the previous content retained by the mail composer object.

Comment: @ErikSapir Yes `MidhunMP` is right, you can't retrieve Draft from within the app, thats what I said, it is saved in your Mail Client.

Comment: Oh, actually it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!